# PayPal Subscription Update Next Billing Date

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to integrate with the PayPal REST API to handle subscriptions (Billing Agreements). The issue I'm facing now is that I don't know how to handle Vouchers that are claimed on my site. I want to change the next billing date to skip the next `x` months but I don't know a way to do this.

How can I skip the next `x` months of a billing agreement?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you want to change the state of the billing agreement to "suspended".